# Temporarily disable blackboxing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I blackeboxed a bunch of scripts. Is it possible to temporary disable the blackboxing or do I have to delete all scripts from the blackbox list?

Answer (score 1):

I work on the DevTools team. Looks like we're missing the ability to temporarily disable blackboxing. Please star this feature request. More stars = higher priority. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=954253